# Is there a way to add line break in react-native-email?

Tags: react-native

I have a feedback page, I am looking to have a section where onPress of a button the application opens the users default email service application and sends typed user feedback to a pre-configured email. I have accomplished all of this using react-native-email.

The captured user TextInput does go into the body of the email. However, there are no line breaks and this looks cluttered. I'm hoping to understand if there are any formatting tools to use with react-native-email, or if there is a way to simply add line breaks.

Here is the sample code

````
  handleEmail = () => {
    const to = ['caleb.dockal@gmail.com'];
    email(to, {
      cc: ['caleb.dockal@gmail.com'],
      subject: 'Feedback',
      body:
        'What feature would you like to see in the app?' +
        '\n' +
        this.state.answer1 +
        '\n' +
        ' How could we improve your experience? ' +
        '\n' +
        this.state.answer2 +
        '\n' +
        ' How can we improve the rating system? ' +
        this.state.answer3 +
        ' What information would you like to see about listed businesses? ' +
        this.state.answer4 +
        ' How did you hear about the app? ' +
        this.state.answer5 +
        ' What countries would you like to see the app in? ' 
        this.state.answer6,
    }).catch(console.error);
  };```

I have tried inserting '\n' in between the strings and state objects and this does not work. Does anyone know of a solution?
````

Comment: first things I see: for `\n` to work you have to use `"\n"` and not `'\n'`

Comment: Yes I have changed it to double quotes and the result is still the same. The "\n" interestingly enough does not show up in the email body, so it is clear to me that it isnt being rendered as a string. However, the new line still does not show.

Comment: have you tried using backticks?

Comment: Yes I have tried using backticks